# COM Interop (how to pass an array to the com) via classic ASP

Tags: c#, .net, asp-classic, com-interop

I need to create a com object for my classic asp, since i can create a .net Assembly and have it 'Interop' with com, so i proceeded to create a .net Assembly like this:-

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Data;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Web;


namespace LMS
{

[ComVisible(true)]
public class Calc
{

    public int Add(int val1, int val2, out string[] outputz)
    {
        int total = val1 + val2;
        outputz = new string[5];
        outputz[1] = "test2";
        outputz[2] = "test3";
        outputz[3] = "test4";
        outputz[4] = "test5";
        return total;
    }


}
}
```

Next i did the usual, build, ran: gacutil & RegAsm

and in my classic asp page  i had this:-

```
Dim params  
dim objPassport3
set objPassport3 = Server.CreateObject("LMS.Calc")
comTest2 = objPassport3.Add(1,1,params)
```

and i get error:

> Error Type:
>   Microsoft VBScript runtime (0x800A0005)
>   Invalid procedure call or argument: 'Add'
>   /eduservice/test.asp, line 25

But if i modify the assembly not to use an array, it all just work, i can even send normal string or int to and from the assembly to classic asp.
i read so many things but i get the same error,

anyone tried this before and was successful, please do share your solution

thanks

Answer (score 10, accepted):

ASP can only handle arrays that are variant, rather than arrays of strings or ints. So try using an object instead, e.g.,

```
public int Add(int val1, int val2, out object outputz)
{
    int total = val1 + val2;
    outputz = new object[5]
      {
          "test1",
          "test2",
          "test3",
          "test4",
          "test5"
      };

    return total;
}
```

Comment: thanks so much for the reply...cant wait to try..will update you on the status

Comment: OrbMan, thanks, you solved my problem, wish i could treat you for lunch.

Comment: This is the same for VBScript.  Even though you can `CreateObject` complex types exposed through COM from VBScript, you cannot pass them back into a method from a .NET assembly unless the complex parameters of that method are of type object.  Primitives (e.g., string, int, etc.) are fine.