# return Array from C# to Classic ASP with COM

Tags: c#, asp.net, com, asp-classic

I am trying to return an array from c# to classic asp using com. [This post helped me lot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1356755/com-interop-how-to-pass-an-array-to-the-com-via-classic-asp), but I still have problems:

I have the following method in c#:

```
public object[] returnStuff () {
    return new object[] {'1','2','3'};
}
```

My classic ASP:

```
dim responseArray1

responseArray1 = RegusSoapComponent.returnStuff()

response.write("Type of Array one is " & VarType(responseArray1))
response.write("Type of Array one is " & responseArray1(1))
```

My output is:

```
response is Type of Array one is 8204
```

> Microsoft VBScript runtime error '800a01ca'
>
> Variable uses an Automation type not supported in VBScript

No matter what I do, I don't seem to be able to access this variable.

Comment: Try return new object[3] {'1','2','3'}; ?

Comment: @Gage: That won't make any difference at runtime.

Comment: @SLaks, I don't think it will either but thats the only difference I see between his and the example he posted.

Comment: @IKode "The Array function, on the other hand, always creates an array of Variants-VarType 8204 (which is 8192 plus 12)." Taken from this page http://www.brainbell.com/tutors/Visual_Basic/Arrays.htm. So you are creating an array of variants. Whats the length of the array returned?

Comment: What if you try to return array of strings? `return new object[] {"1", "2", "3"};` maybe for some reason `char` type is causing problems..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

VBScript likes to receive a variant containing a safearray of variants. So you need to return an object wrapping your array of objects. eg:

```
public object returnStuff() {
    return new object[] {'1','2','3'};
}
```

which should get marshalled the right way. See [a previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5079200/how-to-correctly-marshal-vb-script-arrays-to-and-from-a-com-component-written-in/5097474#5097474) for the detailed version.